# Gravity turn ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I go about solving (or approximating a solution to) this system of differential equations?

### $$
\dot v = g(n - \cos \beta),\\
v\dot \beta = g \sin \beta
$$

[(picture of equations)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuoHz.jpg)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You missed the dot above the beta in the second equation. And why did you make it a heading?

Comment: @Rahul fixed, thanks

Comment: @Rahul thanks for catching that! I just copied the image of the system from Wikipedia

Comment: @Rahul Fixed, thanks. I made it a heading so that it would be larger and therefore easier to read

Comment: For those reading the question interested in context, [this seems to be the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_turn#Mathematical_description) from which the equation was taken.

Comment: If we can assume that the overall change in $\beta$ is small over the time scale, then we can simplify the ODE by taking a first-order approximation of sine and cosine.

Comment: You could also approximate the solution using the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) or some other [Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Comment: It should be mentioned that often $n$ is dependent on $t$, which makes things even more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dv}{dt} = g(n - \cos \beta)\\
v\frac{d\beta}{dt} = g \sin \beta
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad \frac{dv}{v}=\frac{n - \cos \beta}{ \sin \beta}d\beta$$
$$\ln|v|=\int \frac{n - \cos \beta}{ \sin \beta}d\beta$$
$$\boxed{v=c_1\frac{(1 - \cos \beta)^n}{ \sin^{n+1} \beta}}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{d\beta}{dt} = \frac{g}{c_1} \frac{\sin^{n+2} \beta}{(1 - \cos \beta)^n}$$

$$\boxed{t=\frac{c_1}{g}\int \frac{(1 - \cos \beta)^n}{\sin^{n+2} \beta}d\beta+c_2}\tag 2$$
This is the analytic solution for $t$ as a function of $\beta$. The inverse function is $\beta(t)$. Puting it into Eq.$(1)$ gives $v(t)$.

Unfortunately integral and inverse function are not elementary. $v(t)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. One have to use numerical methods of calculus.